# Trying to do Dependency Injection on reflection loaded modules in .NET 6

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to load a handful of assemblies into my main application. Those assemblies need a dbContext that I have set up for DI in the main application.
In the main application I have the following code which gets the appropriate assemblies from the bin directory.

```cs
var rulesList = Directory
    .GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll")
    .Select(x => System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(x))
    .SelectMany(a => a
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(p =>
            p.IsClass &&
            p.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IMyRuleService))
        )
        .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
        .Cast<IMyRuleService>()
    )
    .ToList();
```

This works fine to load the assemblies but I am not sure how to inject the `dbContext` into the assemblies. Because the constructors can not have parameters I've thought about using method injection, but that may be an issue because there may be a varying number of DB contexts to inject. I suppose I could use Method injection to send in an array of all dbContexts that are available but not sure if that is a good way.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

***** Adding code from the assembly being called.

```
public class RuleService : IRedFlagRuleService
{
        private readonly MyDbContext _myDbContext ;    
        public RuleService(MyDbContext myDbContext)
        {
            _myDbContext = myDbContext; 
        }
                
        public Rule GetRuleInfo()
        {
            var ruleAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var rule = _myDbContext.Rules.Where(a => a.AssemblyName == ruleAssembly.GetName().Name).FirstOrDefault() ?? new Rule();    
            return rule;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't use reflection to create the objects. Just tell your container what types to create, let it worry about instantiating instances and resolving dependencies on the constructor.

Comment: As an aside: your `Type` predicate (with  `p.IsClass`) needs to check that `p` actually has a constructor and isn't `abstract`, otherwise `Activator.CreateInstance` will fail. When using DI you can still use reflection, but use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` instead of `Activator`, as `ActivatorUtilities` will use MEDI's `IServiceProvider` to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` instead of `System.Activator.CreateInstance`

  - You will need a reference to the `IServiceProvider` exposed by your MEDI (`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`) `IHost`'s built `ServiceCollection`.
- `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` will use the provided `IServiceProvider` to resolve constructor parameters whose types are registered services.

  - BTW, any additional parameters (e.g. that cannot be resolved by `IServiceProvider`) can be passed-in via the `params Object[] parameters` parameter, but this will necessarily be type-specific (unless *all* of your `IRulesService` implementations have identical ctor parameters, which is unlikely).

Like so:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

//

IHost host = ...
IServiceProvider sp = host.Services; // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihost.services?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#microsoft-extensions-hosting-ihost-services

List<IMyRuleService> rulesList = Directory
    .GetFiles( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll" )
    .Select( fileName => AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath( fileName ) )
    .SelectMany( assembly => assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where( t =>
            t.IsClass &&
            !t.IsAbstract &&
            t.IsAssignableTo( typeof(IMyRuleService) ) &&
            t.GetConstructors( /*BindingFlags.NonPublic*/ ).Length > 0
        )
        .Select( type => (IMyRuleService)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance( sp, type ) )
    )
    .ToList();
```

I modified your `.Where()` predicate to check for `Type.IsAbstract == false` and that it has at least one constructor (uncomment the `BindingFlags` argument to allow `private` and `internal` constructors to count).

Comment: I've got this part working properly now thanks to @Dai's post.  The problem I'm having now is how to retrieve the injected services in the assemblies loaded via ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance.

Comment: @JohnS _"how to retrieve the injected services in the assemblies loaded via `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`"_ - what do you mean by that? The `rulesList` object in the code **is** the result of retrieving those services...

Comment: Maybe retrieve was the wrong word.  I should have said use the injected service in the loaded assembly.  
i.e. I have a dbcontext that I am injecting but when I try to use that db context in the loaded assembly it is telling me that it can not find it.
I've added the code from the assembly in my original post above.

Comment: @JohnS _"when I try to use that db context in the loaded assembly it is telling me that it can not find it"_ - what do you mean by "it is telling me..." - is that a compiler error message, a runtime exception, something else?

Comment: It's a runtime error.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyEFDBAssembly, Version=1.0.8460.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: ...so is `MyEFDBAssembly.dll` present in the same directory as your `.exe` file? Or in your process's working-directory or `PATH`?

Comment: yes that assembly is present in the same directory as the .exe file. (The same directory where all the assemblies are located)

Comment: …with the exact same version number too? What does the Assembly Bind / Fusion log say? See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer